# Viber on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using Proxy-connection

Tags: proxy, viber

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as Operating System.
I have installed Viber successfully.
But there is Problem, because i am using Proxy to connect to the Internet.
So Viber can not connect to the Internet.
And there is not Option to set Proxy-connection in Viber-Settings.

Is there any solution for this Problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried proxy chains? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/proxychains.1.html

Let me know how it went :)

Comment: 1. hardy was Ubuntu 8.04 so a better link would be [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/proxychains.1.html).  2. It's better to include the essential details in the answer than to simply provide a link, content may change or be removed.

Comment: text messages are sent and received, but I was not able to set up it to send images though